# How to return multiple objects as array in GraphQL

Tags: graphql

I would like to query for array of objects in graphql.

I have tried something like:

```
{
    imageSharp(id: {regex: "/whales/"}) {
        data: [
            resize(width: 300, height: 800 ) {
                src
                width
            },
            resize(width: 400, height: 1000 ) {
                src
                width
            },
            resize(width: 500, height: 1200 ) {
                src
                width
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Is it possible or should I write separate name for each object

```
{
  imageSharp(id: {regex: "/whales/"}) {
    data1: resize(width: 300, height: 800) {
      src
      width
    }
    data2: resize(width: 400, height: 1000) {
      src
      width
    }
    data3: resize(width: 500, height: 1200) {
      src
      width
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't query an array like in your first example,
But from what i see you want to retrieve sevral "resize" results based on different filters to a single array,

the only possible way to do this is either giving aliases for different filter options like your second query example but then it'll be in sevral arrays,

or to change the filter object on the "resize" resolver to retrieve an array of width, height and thus return the result in a single array

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your schema how is it build? 
If your schema supports only returning one object then you will need to make multiple queries. But your server might support batch queries. Then you will avoid multiple requests to the server. 
https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/query-batching-in-apollo-63acfd859862